# Does there exist an arbitrary-precision convex optimization solver?

Tags: precision, floating-point, convex-optimization, conditioning

I have a relatively simple convex optimization problem that involves less than 100 variables but contains a terribly ill-conditioned matrix.  I have tried CVX and CPLEX; even though both can typically solve the problem in about 1 second, both fail when the condition number of the matrix becomes very large.  An arbitrary-precision solver would be able to solve this problem quickly and accurately.  Does any such implementation exist?

**Note:** The conditioning of the problem has been considered in detail and is not part of this question.  I'm just asking about software.

Comment: If the matrix is terribly ill-conditioned, there's always the possibility that you're "asking the wrong question"; see if you can reformulate your original problem so that you don't have to deal with ill-conditioned matrices.

Comment: You are using a penalty method, aren't you? Didn't we have this discussion last week? ;-)

Can you build any of your favorite optimization packages with `__float128`? That would probably be enough to handle your penalty.

Comment: Instead of penalties, could you use constraints and an active set method?

Comment: The ill-conditioning is unrelated to the penalty formulation.  I originally tried it as a constrained feasibility problem and got worse results.

Comment: J.M.: Thanks; I am indeed trying to "ask the question in a different basis"; see my question about orthogonal polynomials: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/32/polynomials-that-are-orthogonal-over-curves-in-the-complex-plane

Comment: I guess my question should be, why is the system so close to singular? If its due to multiple solutions, can it be regularized to pick out one? I am thinking here of what happens when removing highly oscillatory solutions.

Comment: The matrix involved is not square, but rather tall and thin.  The most obvious formulation of the problem involves a large Vandermonde matrix, but over points in the complex plane.  So it's ill-conditioned because I don't know how to choose a polynomial basis that is well conditioned with respect to arbitrary sets of points in the complex plane.

Comment: Have you considered [B-splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline) or [radial basis functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function) for your basis?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no complete library that does what you are looking for, but parts of it are available. [MPMath](http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) is an arbitrary precision library for Python that contains a matrix module with linear algebra functionality. It should not be too difficult to implement a convex solver with this library.

**Note.** I agree with the comments above. If a numerical problem is terribly ill-conditioned, I'd recommend that you understand why, and try to improve the description of the problem to lower the condition number.

Comment: I know almost nothing about implementing a convex solver, but if somebody wanted to do it that would be wonderful.

Comment: I have trouble with this answer only because "implement a convex solver" can range from "let's implement Newton's method" to something like "let's flesh out an SQP algorithm with good initial guess and adaptive step-size heuristics". It's absolutely correct in principle, but nontrivial (and probably slightly time-consuming) in practice. Also, from an optimization perspective, it's probably not research-worthy on its own unless you can demonstrate it on a class of ill-conditioned problems that are important in practice (maybe David's problems would suffice?).

Answer (score 2):

''I don't know how to choose a polynomial basis that is well conditioned with respect to arbitrary sets of points in the complex plane.''

If the set of points is bounded, a good basis of polynomials of degree $d$ to use is the Lagrange polynomials of $d+1$ reasonably spaced point along an enclosing contour. This will give you far better results than a multiprecision solution of a problem involving a Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: Thanks; that's exactly what we're using in order to improve conditioning, but eventually it still gets bad.

Answer (score 1):

Here is complete (with the exception of sparse matrices) package for linear algebra in arbitrary precision:

[Multiprecision Computing Toolbox for MATLAB](http://www.advanpix.com/)

It integrates smoothly with Matlab and provides routines for all common operations from determinants to SVD and eigenvalues.

Actually it also covers other areas - numerical integration, optimization, ode, special functions, etc.

As for function minimization you could try Nelder–Mead simplex method (`fminsearch`) implemented in the toolbox too.